# Add more than 5 web parts to same web page in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I tried to add more than 5 web parts to a single webpart/page in SharePoint Online but I am not able to do that.

 the result which i am getting is as like.
[image]
Any idea why this is not possible?

Comment: What is the outcome or any error message?

Comment: it shows the message like"The maximum number of Sandbox Solution Web Parts on this page has been exceeded." after adding 6th web part

Answer (score 2):

I think its not the issue with keeping 6th WebPart, its an issue with the server resource quotas for sandboxed solutions.

Please have a look to the following article.

[Manage SharePoint Online server resource quotas for sandboxed solutions](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Manage-SharePoint-Online-server-resource-quotas-for-sandboxed-solutions-90e4eaaa-899a-48d6-b850-f272366bf8cc)

Let me know whether i am correctly getting your problem's solution.

Thanks

Comment: nope ,it's not working

Comment: What you have tried for this?

Comment: increased the server resource quota

Comment: please have a look to the given discussion https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/425233. It may provide you hint. i am too trying to reproduce the error here

Comment: that is same as like the above article, i tried this link as well,but stil reslt is zero